# Android Kotlin change multi-language

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image: Android Studio Kotlin change multi-language]

How can I change language realtime? 
Because in this image when I want to change need restart activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to restart your activity, can using below way

```
private void updateResource(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
                updateResource((ViewGroup) view);
            else {
                if(view.getTag()==null){
                    continue;
                }
                int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(view.getTag().toString(), “string”, getPackageName());
                if(view instanceof EditText){
                    EditText editText=(EditText)view;
                    editText.setHint(getString(resId));
                }else if(view instanceof TextView){
                    TextView textView=(TextView) view;
                    textView.setText(getString(resId));
                }else if(view instanceof Button){
                    Button button=(Button) view;
                    button.setText(getString(resId));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Beside that, in your xml layout, add a tag for every view which has string
example:

```
android:text=“@string/text_example”
android:tag=“text_example”
```

Hope this helps

Comment: you're welcome, note that if you using `createConfigurationContext(configuration)`, remember getting string resource from you new context